# Linux system logs

Tags: files, logs, aws, certificates

In one of our AWS Linux virtual machines, the `ca-certificate.crt` file has been modified, and our private CA has been deleted.

How can I determine who made these changes and deletions?

Comment: Some might consider this to fall under the category of how-to questions and mark it for closure but are there not people who have an understanding of how to manage Linux infrastructure and the implementation and usage of tools such as `auditd`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot -- after the fact. For the future, you can set up `auditd` to audit the filesystem. The following command sets up a watch over a file:

```
auditctl -w /path/to/filetowatch -k myfile -p rwxa
```

You can then check the logs via `ausearch`.

According to the principle of least privilege, I would also check who has root access on your AWS server and verify the sudoers file, to remove anyone who does not need privileged access.